# DataGridViewComboBoxCell - needs 2 clicks to get the current selected index

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have this code :

```
private void vicationDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (zawag) {
                ComboBox cbo = e.Control as ComboBox;
                if (cbo != null)
                {
                    if (cbo.SelectedIndex == 6)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("test");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

When I run my app, this code will not work untill I click the combobox 2 times and sometimes 3 clicks, I need to let it work for the first click when the user select value for the first time.

I tried to set the EditMode to EditOnEnter but the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your DataGridView's `EditingControlShowing` event to add an event handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the ComboBox in your grid.  You can move the code you have for testing the ComboBox's `SelectedIndex` to the method that's invoked when the `SelectedIndexChanged` event fires.

There's a great example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).